# Prove that the probability that exactly of one of events A and B occurs is P(A)+P(B)-2P(A∩B)

Tags: probability-theory

The Probability of $A$ without $B = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$
The Probability of $B$ without $A = P(B) - P(A\cap B)$

Get the union, thus adding them together 
$P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$

Does $P(A) - P(A\cap B)$ not allow the events of $B$ that are not in $A$ to still occur?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: I believe there's an error there, although not central. $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) says that

$$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$$

If you define probability of an event as
$$P(A)=\frac{|A|}{|S|}$$
Where $S$ is the sampling set, then:
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $P(A)-P(A\cap B)$ is the probability that $A$ occures and $B$ doesn't occure. In other words, it is the probability that $A\cap B^c$ occures where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$.